# Highlight edited cells of WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am currently working on an app displaying data I am querying from a database into a DataGrid.

As the columns of the table are not know in advanced, I was not able to implement the DataGrid as an ObservableCollection of objects, and the DataGrid is consequently binded to a DataTable:

```
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = _myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Users should be able to edit data directly in the DataGrid, and the edited cells should be highlighted.

At the moment, the only progress I was able to make on that matter was to use the `CellEditEnding` event to change the color of the cell:

```
private void MyDataGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
        DataGridCell gridCell = null;
        if (sender is DataGrid dg)
        {
            gridCell = GetCell(dg.CurrentCell);
        }

        if (gridCell != null)
            gridCell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;

    }
}

public DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo)
{
    if (!dataGridCellInfo.IsValid)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var cellContent = dataGridCellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(dataGridCellInfo.Item);
    return (DataGridCell) cellContent?.Parent;
}
```

This approach works well if a user edits a cell by double-clicking on it, changing the value and pressing enter to commit the changes.

However, it fails if the user edits the cell and commits the editing by clicking on a new row. In this case, the new cell is colored rather than the edited one, which makes sense as `dg.CurrentCell` evaluates to the new selected cell.

What are possible leads to color the edited cell rather than the newly selected cell?

Do you know of a better approach to highlight edited cells from a DataGrid bonded to a DataTable?

Comment: Check this out: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html

Comment: I just tried that link, and it does not seem to be working, but I'll see if I find resources relevant to my specific use case from this author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, using the CurrentCell won't work because it changes when selecting a different cell. The OnCellEditEnding event provides the edited element in the event arguments but you need to get the DataGridCell that it is contained in to change cell properties. I too wish it would just be provided but you need to walk up the visual tree to get it:

```
private void MyDataGrid_OnCellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
    {
            DependencyObject depObj = e.EditingElement;
            while (depObj != null && !(depObj is DataGridCell)) {
                depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent (depObj);
            }

            if (depObj != null) {
                DataGridCell gridCell = (DataGridCell) depObj;
                gridCell.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
    }
}
```